# Passing scope variable to function in ng-click

Tags: javascript, angularjs

So I know I must be missing some basic part of javascript with this quesiton but here it goes anyhow:

I have a contoller that has a variable declared in it:

```
$scope.IsStartDatePickerHidden = true;
$scope.IsEndDatePickerHidden = true;
```

I have a button that has its ng-click set to go to a function in my controller. This function would be nice if it took in a parameter which it can change the value:

```
<button type="button" ng-click="showDatePicker(IsStartDatePickerHidden)" >

 $scope.showDatePicker = function(showDatePicker)
 {
     showDatePicker = false;
 }
```

when I step through this code the function showDatePicker changes the value of the parameter that is passed in but does not seem to change the value of the variable in the controller, so nothing happens. I am sure this has to be something to do with passing by reference. I am just not sure how to pass this in  so that $scope.IsStartDatePickerHidden or $scope.IsEndDatePickerHidden are changed depending on which one I pass in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The how-to-fix-that-example **Fiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/p3p6ova7/

If you know the variables you want to work with on your scope, there is no need to pass in those values.  In your case, you were initializing a new variable within your functon, `showDatePicker`, and assigning false to that, which wouldn't have any effect on `$scope.IsStartDatePickerHidden`

You could also simply do `ng-click="IsStartDatePickerHidden = false"`, but that may be a little outside best practice.

Comment: I have other things I need to do inside the function or I would just do it inline.

Comment: Then use multiple functions or `ng-click="showDatePicker('IsStartDatePickerHidden')` and `$scope.showDatePicker(name) { $scope[name] = false; }` as Constantinos suggested.

Answer (score 6):

Brad's answer is correct, but just in case you wanted something for more general use, so that you can change the value of any scope variable:

```
<button type="button" ng-click="showDatePicker('IsStartDatePickerHidden')" >

 $scope.showDatePicker = function(varName)
 {
     $scope[varName] = false;
 }
```

This is not necessarily good practice, but often useful. Speaking of which, you could just do the assignment inside the ng-click:

```
<button type="button" ng-click="IsStartDatePickerHidden = false" >
```

Comment: Interesting I never thought of $scope as a key value collection but it makes perfect sense.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Solved a problem that took about 2 days of my time. Thanks for sharing.